# HP Pavilion Media Center a1630n Desktop PC upgrade to Windows 7 64?

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, 64-bit, upgrade, hp-pavilion

I have a HP Pavilion Media Center a1630n Desktop PC. With Windows XP Media Center 32bit.  I also have 4GB of memory installed.

Specs [here](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?docname=c00753784&tmp_task=prodinfoCategory&lc=en&dlc=en...)

I want to upgrade to Windows 7 Ultimate 64bit.  I know my processor is 64 compatible (Athlon 64 X2 (W) 4600+ 2.4 GHz)

I have read that going to a 64bit OS is more than just the processor.  You also have to make sure there are drivers available for your computer to run it correctly.  If I go to the downloads section for my computer at:

http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/softwareCategory?lc=en&dlc=en&cc=us&lang=en&product=3245027&

and choose Windows 7 64, there are no drivers.  Either for the Windows 7 32bit.  So does this mean I should not upgrade to Windows 7 64?  And if shouldn't, can I upgrade to Windows 7 32bit?

I ran the 7 upgrade advisor, and I get all green check marks for both 32 and 64, except for:

- Custom installation required

  > You'll need to perform a custom installation of 32-bit Windows 7 and then reinstall your programs. Make sure to back up your files before you begin. Go online to get important information about installing Windows 7 on a PC running Windows XP
- Outlook Express

  > This program is no longer included in Windows 7. You can get similar programs for Windows 7 from other software manufacturers. Go to the Microsoft website to learn more
- More info from ASUSTeK Computer INC.

  > ASUSTeK Computer INC. has a website that might give you more information about getting Windows 7 running on your PC.
  >   Visit the ASUSTeK Computer INC. website

The first 2 are no problem.  As for the 3rd, does this mean there might be an issue with my motherboard?

Comment: It does list a few for vista. As far as I know, drivers that work on vista 64 should be fine for win7 64. But the listing only has a few specific drivers. If possible you might try making a new partition (or if you have an extra hard drive lying around, use it) and then try installing win7 on that. The drivers built into windows are good enough for most situations but I wouldn't bet the farm on it.

Answer (score 1):

My apologies if this is *WAY* out of date.. wanted to contribute..

I have the same system; XP media center was having problems due to things happening under the admin-level account that i couldn't figure out... my solution? Install Win7 on it..  i installed Win7 64-bit on it with very few problems.. the only thing that didn't work after the 7 install was my printer (HP Deskjet 6122) - i ended up installing a DJ 990c driver according to HP's website, and everything has been working since..

Hope this helps.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Windows 7 should have all the motherboard drivers when it installs, I doubt it will be an issue, after W7 installs, check device manager for any missing drivers.